# VueJS: Fire jQuery after v-for?

Tags: jquery, vue.js, zurb-foundation

I'm rendering a list of features with v-for that uses Foundation's accordion-menu jQuery to nest a drop down within an unordered list... but can't figure out how to create the accordion, since v-for is rendered after my mounted() function... Here's my code:

```
<template>
    <div class="off-canvas position-left" id="filters" data-off-canvas>

    <!-- Close button -->
        <button class="close-button" aria-label="Close menu" type="button" data-close>
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>

    <!-- Menu -->
        <h3>Choose a Filter</h3>
        <ul class="vertical menu" data-accordion-menu>

            <li v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id">
                <a href="#">{{ category.name }}</a>
                <ul class="menu vertical nested">
                    <li v-for="feature in category.features" :key="feature.id">
                        <a href="#">{{ feature.name }}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['categories'],
        mounted() {
            this.loadFoundation()
        },
        unmounted() {
            $(this.$el).foundation.destroy();
        }
    }
</script>
```

I've tried utilizing the $nextTick feature, both within the mounted() hook like this:

```
mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(function() {
      $(this.$el).foundation();
    })
}
```

Or as its own method, like this:

```
methods: {
  loadFoundation() {
    this.$nextTick(function() {
      $(this.$el).foundation();
    })
  }
},
mounted() {
  this.loadFoundation()
}
```

But neither works correctly (it initializes my off-canvas menu, but not the accordion menu within the v-for). Do I need to use a watch function, instead? I feel like there has to be an easier way to do this, but integrating jQuery with Vue is honestly making me want to rip my hair out at this point :D

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but it sounds like you may want to use another hook than `mounted()`. Check the lifecycle diagram at https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram whether that's helpful for you.

Comment: updated() is what you are looking for. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated

Comment: Also, if you plan on using a lot of jquery plugins in your project, I would thoroughly recommend setting them up as a custom Vue directive. Issues like this can then be resolved at a directive level, which increases reusability. https://gambardella.info/2016/09/05/guide-how-to-use-vue-js-with-jquery-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a watch on the `categories` prop and fire it on change:

```
export default {
  props: ['categories'],
  watch: {
    'categories': function (val, oldVal) {
      $(this.$el).foundation();
    }
  }
})
```